# SharePoint. How to run timerjob every 90 minutes

Tags: sharepoint, timer-jobs

I have a web.config setting like IntervalInMinutes. I would like to use the setting value to create my SPSchedule instance and run my job. The interval should be set in minutes.

I know how to use SPMinuteSchedule and run the job every 0 < n < 60 minute or how to use SPHourSchedule and run the job every 0 < n < 24 hours, But what if I want to have 90 or 2000 minutes interval as the setting value?

So, the question is: what should I do to run the job with the minutes interval 0 < n < 100000?

Thank you.

Comment: Belongs here: [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very robust solution, but I think you'll have to use an appropriate number of the `SPDailySchedule` objects.

In case of the 90 minutes interval it is:

```
24 h / 1.5 h = 16
```